# convert json object (php date) with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, date

I have the following json object date that comes from php, and I need to display date with javascript in user timezone in dd/mm/YYYY HH:mn format:

```
{ "date": "2018-05-01 22:06:01.000000", 
  "timezone_type": 3, 
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin" 
}
```

Comment: JSON is designed to be received by javascript as an oblect. So `var.date` would do it

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, what about timezone ?

Comment: If at all possible (if you control the server-side code), avoid using any dates not in UTC format. The only time you should ever use timezones is to display data, right before you display it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `moment.js` an excellent library for handling dates

https://momentjs.com/

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

```js
let json = { "date": "2018-05-01 22:06:01.000000", 
  "timezone_type": 3, 
  "timezone": "Europe/Berlin" 
};

let date =  moment.tz(json.date, json.timezone);

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.17/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```